# 'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'

Tags: r, plot

i am trying to plot a ROC curve for a multiclass problem, using multiclass.roc function from pROC package, but I get this error:

```
'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'
```

What does this error mean cause searching in the web didn't help me to find an answer. I can print the roc object, but can not plot it.

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. Paste the output from `dput(yourdata)` and the code that generated the error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you call `plot` on a list `l`: `plot (l)`, the x coordinates will be taken from `l$x` and the y coordinates from `l$y`. Your list doesn't have elements x and y.

You need to call `plot (l$your.x.coordinate, l$your.y.coordinate)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Another (lazy) approach is to simply use the `useful` library

```
install.packages('useful')
library(useful)
```

**Example -**

```
wineUrl <- 'http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine/wine.data'
wine <- read.table(wineUrl, header=F, sep=',')
wine_kmeans <- wine[, which(names(wine) != "Cultivar")]
wine_cluster <- kmeans(x=wine_kmeans , centers=3)
plot(wine_cluster, data=wine_kmeans)
```

[image]

Comment: Which function from useful is called in your example? I only see plot.kmeans (implied in the plot function), but I don't think that is related to the original question.